# Comparing latitude and longitude between two dataframes

Tags: r, merge, geospatial, distance

I have two dataframes in R; one dataframe contains the latitude and longitude of counties (df1) and the other contains the latitude and longitude of points of interest (df2). I was hoping to come up with a for loop that iterates through the df1 rows, while searching to see if any latitude/longitude points in df2 fall within a certain distance from the other points (say the coordinates of one point are (-88.40,42.82), it would scan for any points within df2 ((-88.40+/-1.5,42,82+/-1.5)), and if the answer is yes/no I would like to create a new column that contains the answer.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
for(x,y in 1:nrow(df1){if(x +/- 1.5 %in% df2 & y +/- 1.5 %in% df2){
df1.append("yes")
}
else{
df1.append("no")
}
```

I know the function for this is not .append() in R, I just am uncertain how to go about doing this. It would be less complicated if only scanning for matching points, but as it is a geospatial distance, I wanted to scan for a sort of radius and I am lost on this.

Comment: You are asking for a left non-equi-join, i.e find matches in teh county dataframe with locations in second dataframe based on a calculated distance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your quetsion is somewhat vague, but here is one approach. As I don't have yuor data, I make stuff up. It became a rather global region.

The good news is that package geosphere comes with a function ready to calculate the distance matrix you ask for.

In addition to this I reshape it to a "county by county" table that easily filtered on any ditsance criterion you might have.

```r
df <- data.frame(
    County = paste( "County", 1:100 ),
    Long = runif( 100, -180, 180 ),
    Lat = runif( 100, -90, 90 )
)

library(tibble)
library(geosphere)

dist.matrix <- distm( df[,c("Long","Lat")], df[,c("Long","Lat")], fun=distVincentyEllipsoid )
dimnames(dist.matrix) <- list( df$County, df$County )

dist.table <- dist.matrix %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    rownames_to_column("County") %>%
    pivot_longer(cols=matches("County \\d"), values_to="Distance", names_to = "Destination" ) %>%
    rename( Start = County ) %>%
    filter( Start != Destination )

## Any combination of points less than 1000 kilometers from each other:
dist.table %>% filter( Distance < 1e6 )
```

I got this:

```
# A tibble: 92 x 3
   Start     Destination Distance
   <chr>     <chr>          <dbl>
 1 County 1  County 27    689265.
 2 County 1  County 82    563744.
 3 County 2  County 28    463513.
 4 County 2  County 47    890841.
 5 County 3  County 66    668010.
 6 County 7  County 41    512246.
 7 County 9  County 100   600399.
 8 County 11 County 44    217320.
 9 County 12 County 66    861757.
10 County 14 County 94    372178.
# … with 82 more rows
```

You can easily filter on counties, distance, arrange by county etc, to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

The fuzzyjoin package has a geographic distance function built in to handle exactly this siguation:

```
if(!require(fuzzyjoin)){install.packages("fuzzyjoin");library(fuzzyjoin)}
#Loading required package: fuzzyjoin

df1 <- data.frame(lon=-88.40,lat=42.82)
df2 <- data.frame(lon = -88.40, lat= 42.82)

geo_join(df1,df2, max_dist=2) 
# figured max_dist=2 would be ok if 1.5 were tol. on both lat and lon
#Joining by: c("lon", "lat")
#  lon.x lat.x lon.y lat.y
#1 -88.4 42.82 -88.4 42.82
```

There is also a `geo_full_join` that would return rows from both dataframes with NA's in the corresponding columns for locations that did not have a neighboring location within the max dist. I put in a couple of other locations on the other side of the world and get this:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(lon=c(-88.40, 40),lat=c(42.82, 40)); 
 df2 <- data.frame(lon = c(-88.40, 20), lat= c(42.82, 20))
> df1
    lon   lat
1 -88.4 42.82
2  40.0 40.00

> geo_join(df1,df2, max_dist=10)

Joining by: c("lon", "lat")
  lon.x lat.x lon.y lat.y
1 -88.4 42.82 -88.4 42.82

> geo_left_join(df1,df2, max_dist=10)

Joining by: c("lon", "lat")
  lon.x lat.x lon.y lat.y
1 -88.4 42.82 -88.4 42.82
2  40.0 40.00    NA    NA

> geo_full_join(df1,df2, max_dist=10)

Joining by: c("lon", "lat")
  lon.x lat.x lon.y lat.y
1 -88.4 42.82 -88.4 42.82
2  40.0 40.00    NA    NA
3    NA    NA  20.0 20.00
```